# Segmentation Fault Only during Blender Rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a system where I create the blender files on my laptop (mac) and sync it through dropbox to my Ubuntu desktop. This has been working fine, but recently I have a complex file where I have a few different linked libraries. The file opens fine, but on both computers now it gives me a segmentation fault whenever I go to render. I have a similar problem with another file, but in that case I can only open without getting a segmentation error on my Mac. When I pack and unpack linked libraries the file size doesn't seem to change either.

I believe it has to do with one of the linked libraries' hierarchies being corrupted somehow. But does anyone have any ideas for how to go about debugging? This is all I'm getting in the terminal:

Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
Writing: /var/folders/0j/zc4p0_ks69x26h_cfh7yn_xw0000gn/T/5. Cat Rescue attempted fix.crash.txt
rmdir: No such file or directory
zsh: segmentation fault  blender -d

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problems so I will follow this with some interest. Have you tried running the render in terminal?...the argument for debugging is "--debug" or "-d" or "-d --debug cycles".

I have been getting "Invalid cloners with this fan!" and thought it might be to do with some custom normals.

I can render about 10 frames at a time before the render will either crash blender or freeze building optix acceleration structure. I get "segmentation fault (core dumped)" when blender crashes. I have tried everything I can think of. Turning off "Persistent Data" yields some improvement. It will render 10 frames as opposed to crashing immediately.

Also, the file is well optimised. GPU is 5.6/8 Gb, and RAM is 18/64 Gb.

Can you try the debugging command and see how you get on? (PS - I'm Ubuntu as well).